# Onde encontro exemplos de códigos de programas simples feitos totalmente em Java?

Tags: java

Onde encontro exemplos de códigos de programas simples feitos totalmente em Java?
    Preciso de links!

Comment: procure “java hello world”, no google

Comment: Alguns links que podem ajudar a aproveitar melhor o site: [ask] | [A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](/help/on-topic) | [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lista de alguns que encontrei:

1. [Java Coding Samples](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/codingSamples.htm)
2. [Java Examples](http://www.java-examples.com/)
3. [Java Example Program](https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~sloan/CLASSES/java/)